# Where to implement backend filter logic in Web-based frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, web, api-design

If, in a (React-based) web application, I want to fill a selection dropdown list that's content is determined by some backend (Spring Boot) logic depending on input from the UI, e.g.

```
filterOptions(x) return (x < 0) ? [1,2,3] : [4,5,6];
```

The dialog is not opened very often and the client/server communication overhead is neglectable as it is a LAN-based application. I have two approaches in mind:

1) We could build a backend endpoint that is to be queried whenever the user opens the dialog.

2) We could build a more generic endpoint to fetch the filter ruleset and build the filter in the Frontend.

3) your approach here

IMO, 1) is not an ideal approach because it clutters the api with these filter endpoints and couples front- and backend too much while 2) is not much better couplewise and is still weird to implement.

How would you implement this, what questions would you ask to determine which approach is more suited?

Comment: What's the point of (3) if there is nothing written there?

Comment: Why don't you just fetch all the dropdown choices and then filter it in the frontend?

Comment: I think option 1 is still better as we are moving towards the micro services architecture.

Comment: Enter your own idea in 3). Fetching all choices would mean that the filter logic must be implemented in the frontend which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on the size of the dataset and complexity of the ruleset. All datasets of reasonable size should be pulled to client and cached there, this allows the server to cache these requests which allows for fast responses. For complex and large datasets, leave it up to the server.